# React App hosting with GoDaddy.. is it possible?

Tags: reactjs, hosting

I have created reactJs App. Now I want to deploy to make my software live. Also, I have my host and domain in GoDaddy. But I do not have a guideline that how to host reactJs App on GoDaddy. I've gone through various sites but I did not get proper steps. Please help me with this as this is my biggest headache nowadays.

Comment: Have you contacted their support team?

Comment: Actually first I want to know that is it possible to host the reactJs app in GoDaddy?

Comment: You may ask them. Around 8 years ago, I used their service, but not stable so I decided to move. You better find other providers to avoid any headache.

Comment: thank you for your guidance. what about AWS services?

Comment: AWS is cloud service, very easy to deploy, but the minor thing is they are costly. If you have high budget, just go ahead with them, it is very suitable for medium large application. For small site, I won't recommend them, you will be shocked with the fee. For small application, you may also check Asphostportal, I use their shared hosting service.